# DDOS Proxy Provider

Tags: proxy, ddos

I would like to know if anyone has experience with good DDOS Proxy Providers, where it is posible to switch only the NS of the domain and to prevent the attack. Please post any provider, that you have used and you recommend and maybe the price range, because I am collecting now some sorces to find the best one for me. I have found some with price ranges from 299$-699$ for small bussines sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only guys you should trust are:

http://www.gigenet.com/ddos-protection.html and http://www.blacklotus.net/protection/elite-protection/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I helped someone run a website that was risky. I stopped helping him but what you're looking for is [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).
Helps keep you up during attacks. 
I don't know if you know, but a hacking group known as lulzsecurity had a site up for awhile and there were lots of people that didn't want them up. They were successful with cloud flare. 
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use low cost vds-server with ddos-protection and another dedicated server on other host, like this pack :

VDS : http://www.sim-networks.com/ with plan ESXi-M, it include 100Gbp/s DDOS protection

and other Dedicated Server, for example http://www.online.net/en/dedicated-server

All you need to do is to set up nginx proxy from VDS to Dedicated Server